# Kotlin-function with colon symbol and then class name

Tags: function, kotlin

Could someone explain what it means when we write a function with colon symbol and then name of the class, like below?

fun y() : x

here x is name of the class. The function is not inside the curly brackets of the class

What I know, we create object of a class with name of the variable, then colon symbol and then name of the class.

Comment: Did you read the basics about the syntax from the Kotlin documentation? If so, what do you not understand about it?

Comment: I did read. But I am confused whether it is anyway related to scoping. Also, if I declare a function with class after colon, what advantage I get. I know you are all seasoned professionals. I am very new, trying to understand the fundamental

Comment: No worries, just trying to understand which part you needed a better explanation of so we're not just repeating the documentation, which wouldn't be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The class name after the colon is the type of object that the function returns. For instance, if you have a function that wants to take an Int input and return its square as an Int, you would do:

```
fun square(input: Int): Int { 
    return input * input 
}
```

If you try to return an Int without declaring it as the return type with `: Int`, there will be a compiler error.

This doesn't have to do with scoping, but it does mean if you declare a return value like this, then your function **must** return the type you declared. If within the scope of your function you have logical branches, every branch of execution must return that type or `throw`, which is a failure condition. For example:

```
fun squareNullable(input: Int?): Int {
    if (input != null) {
        return input * input
    } else {
        println("Cannot square null input!")
       
        // You will have a compiler error because this branch of logical 
        // execution is not returning an Int.
    }
}
```

If you omit a return type, your function is not allowed to return anything except for the effectively useless `Unit` type.

Use a return type when your function produces a result.

---

There is an optional shorthand function syntax  called "single-expression function" that might be confusing to a newbie. Instead of using `{ }` after the function and returning something with the `return` keyword. You can use `=` and then an expression that is implicitly returned. When you use this syntax, the compiler allows you to omit the return type.

```
fun square(input: Int): Int = input * input 

// Compiler allows you to do this. The ": Int" is implicitly assumed:

fun square(input: Int) = input * input
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for your detailed explanation! Now I understand the nuances of using type while declaring a function. I noticed error while compiling, without return statement, but eroor was not explicit (per Android studio, "A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}'"), I thought, I had to have curly brackets. Thanks once again!